# Multinomial theorem for 0's and 1's

Tags: combinatorics

I'm looking for a special case of [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) where the indeterminates $x_1,\dots,x_m$ only take values $0$ and $1$. The power $n$ can be assumed to be greater than he number of arguments $m$, although the general case together with $n\leq m$ would be even better.

**Edit:** more specifically, I'm looking for a formula that is expressed as a sum of all possible monomials with a maximal degree of an indeterminate equals $1$ (e.g. $x_2, ~x_3x_4x_6, ~x_1x_6$) with some coefficients.

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers thanks, edited the indeterminates part. In this case, all "monomials" $x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_m^{k_m}$ in $x_i$'s lump together based on whether the according indeterminates are simultaneously positive or zero, as $x_i^k  = x_i$. So I'm looking for a formula that takes advantage of that fact with appropriate coefficients.

Comment: So you're looking for a polynomial identity? How would you get rid of monomials like $x_1 x_2$ (this is degree 2, according to the usual definition of degree)?

Comment: @md5 thanks, I definetly lack the right definitions. By "degree 1" I meant the maximal degree of an indeterminate in a monomial, e.g. $x_1, x_2x_4$ are "of degree 1" I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is a formula of the type:

$$(x_1+\ldots+x_m)^n=\sum_{I\subseteq [m]} \alpha_I \prod_{i\in I} x_i$$

modulo $x_i^2-x_i=0$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Note that from the multinomial theorem,

$$\alpha_I=\sum_{k_i\ge 1,\sum_{i\in I} k_i=n} \frac{n!}{\prod_{i\in I} k_i!}.$$

You can check that:

$$\alpha_I=|I|!{n\brace |I|}$$

where ${n\brace k}$ are [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: Note: You don't need to use the multinomial theorem here. All you need is to expand $\left(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_m\right)^n$ and combine like terms. The coefficient in front of $\prod_{i \in I} x_i$ (for a given subset $I$ of $\left[m\right]$) will be the number of all maps $f : \left[n\right] \to \left[m\right]$ whose image is $I$. But this number is the number of all surjective maps from $\left[n\right]$ to $I$, and this is known to be $\left|I\right|! {n \brace \left|I\right|}$.

Comment: @darij grinberg Thanks, very intuitive and helpful.